# How to perform a linear regression with a forced gradient in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to do a linear regression on some limited and scattered data. I know from theory that the gradient should be 1, but it may have a y-offset. I found a lot of resources on how to force an intercept for linear regression, but never on forcing a gradient. I need the linear regression statistics to be reported and the gradient to be precisely 1.
Would I need to manually calculate the statistics? Or is there a way to use some packages like "statsmodels," "scipy," or "scikit-learn"? Or do I need to use a Bayesian approach with previous knowledge of the gradient?

Here is a graphical example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data to illustrate the point

n = 20
x = np.random.uniform(10, 20, n)
y = x - np.random.normal(1, 1, n) # Add noise to the 1:1 relationship

plt.scatter(x, y, ec="k", label="Measured data")

true_x = np.array((8, 20))
plt.plot(true_x, true_x, "k--") # 1:1 line
plt.plot(true_x, true_x-1, "r:", label="Forced gradient") # Theoretical line

m, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(true_x, true_x\*m + c, "g:", label="Linear regression")

plt.xlabel("Theoretical value")
plt.ylabel("Measured value")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Example of forced gradient vs linear regression in random data]

Comment: You can use basic calculus to derive that the solution for the bias (minimizing squared error) is the average of `(y-w*x)`, i.e. `b = sum(y-w*x)/N`. In your case `w=1`.

Comment: That would also work! Thank you! But the solution proposed by @Caridorc is more flexible and gives me the uncertainty in the intercept, which I need for displaying the uncertainty in the fit.

Comment: The same works for ols regression on a constant: `OLS(y-w*x, np.ones(len(y))).fit()` in statsmodels with inference e.g. in `.summary()`. Some other models,  GLM, discrete models, support using `offset=w*x` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that has the benefit of being flexible and easy to use also for non-linear regressions. You just need to define a function that represents a line with a known gradient and an offset given as input:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a):
    gradient = 1 # fixed gradient, not optimized
    return gradient * x + a

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y = func(xdata, 2.5)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y_noise = 0.2 * rng.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
popt
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That generates the plot:

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe that I did not think of this ... I used curve_fit for the forced intercept, but did not think to use it for the gradient.. Thank you for this!

Comment: @DouglasCoenen You are welcome, it happens often to not think about obvious solutions, do not worry